# Running 12.04 LTS as Virtual box on a windows 7 , 64bit OS .Not able to access internet from Ubuntu VM box

Tags: 12.04

Running  12.04 LTS as Virtual box on a windows 7 , 64bit OS .Not able to access internet from Ubuntu VM box. I have a wired Internet connection and able to access internet  from windows 7 .But not able to access from Ubuntu .

Please post your suggestions.

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

In the Virtual Machine Settings:
In the network connection select Bridged:Connect directly to the physical network.
Please tell us if that fixes your problem.